# Is there any way to know all the tables(and/or views, triggers, functions) present in the Oracle 9i database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-9i

I want to know this because I forgot the name of the table I created.

i am using Oracle 9i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login as your user, then execute:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES;
```

Selecting from this data dictionary view will list all of the tables owned by the currently logged in user.

All of the objects you own can either be viewed in their object-specific `USER_` view, or queried in the `USER_OBJECTS` view:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE FROM USER_OBJECTS;
```

For example:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE 
FROM USER_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN ('FUNCTION', 'PACKAGE', 'PACKAGE BODY', 'PROCEDURE');
```

Comment: But I don't know the 'table_name', that' what I want to find!!

Comment: `TABLE_NAME` is the column name in the `USER_TABLES` view, which is obvious if you know SQL. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_5443.htm

Comment: Thanks. Got it! :) And what to know the existing procedures and functions?

Comment: Use `USER_OBJECTS`